# DotNetOpenAuth ctp 4.0 ResourceServer.VerifyAccess() method throwing null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, oauth-2.0, wcf-web-api

I'm having difficulties trying to get DotNetOpenAuth ctp 4.0 to work. Here's the situation:
I have a resource server just like the one on the OAuth2 sample, however I'm using WCF Web Api preview 6, so I wrote an extensibility point in charge of verifiying that the client doing the request to the operation is already authorized to do it, in order to accomplish this, method ResourceServer.VerifyAccess is called. This method is throwing a null exception, and I haven't found out why.

This is how I wrote my operation handler:

```
protected override HttpRequestMessage OnHandle(HttpRequestMessage input)
    {
        var principal = VerifyOAuth2(input);
        if(principal == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
                                                {
                                                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                                                    Content = new StringContent("Invalid Access Token")
                                                });
        }

        var roles = _authorizationAttribute.Roles.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if(!roles.Any(role => principal.IsInRole(role)))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
                Content = new StringContent("User has not permission to access this resource")
            });
        }

        return input;
    }

    private static IPrincipal VerifyOAuth2(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var headers = request.Headers;
        var headersCollection = new WebHeaderCollection();
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            headersCollection.Add(header.Key, header.Value.ToString());
        }

        using (var signing = MvcApplication.CreateAuthorizationServerSigningServiceProvider())
        {
            using (var encrypting = MvcApplication.CreateResourceServerEncryptionServiceProvider())
            {
                var resourceServer = new ResourceServer(new StandardAccessTokenAnalyzer(signing, encrypting));

                IPrincipal result;
                var httpRequestInfo = new HttpRequestInfo(request.Method.ToString(), request.RequestUri,
                                                          request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri, headersCollection, request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);//Since I dont have an HttpResourceInfo Object I need to build one from my request, using an overloaded method. 
                var error = resourceServer.VerifyAccess(httpRequestInfo, out result); //here is where the exception is thrown. 
                // TODO: return the prepared error code.
                return error != null ? null : result;
            }
        }
```

I don't know if this code helps, but in case it doesn't, can you tell me when does this method throws a null reference exception?? maybe that'll help me a bit! thank you in advance.

Comment: question.. where you are doing the Split and passing new [] {" " } are you getting an error there by chance.. not use to seeing it done that way

Comment: No, the exception is being thrown before that, in the VerifyOAuth2() method

Comment: IPrincipal is an interface from .net framework. and input is an object of HttpRequestMessage which is a sealed class from WCF Web Api

Comment: can you step into that code and determine which line it's failing in the VerifyOAuth2 method

Comment: it's failing on this line: var error = resourceServer.VerifyAccess(httpRequestInfo, out result);. It throws a null reference exception

Comment: are you sure that you can't just use the HTTPrequest instead of having to create or over load what you are doing ..something just looks off

Comment: The thing is that I have an HttpRequestMessage which is not the same as HttpRequest, anyways, I would need to build an HttpRequest from my HttpRequestMessage. So I guess is the same thing. I could try though

Comment: yeah because somewhere within that messsage / stream that you are creating there is a null reference meaning that you probably are not creating an new instance of the stream param that you are passing.. I could be wrong but thats where my guess is

Comment: Can you please include the callstack from the NullReferenceException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stacktrace for the `NullReferenceException` would be helpful.

In lieu of that, have you tried obtaining an `HttpRequestMessageProperty` from WCF and passing that to the `HttpRequestInfo` constructor the way the `OAuthAuthorizationManager` does in the sample?